# Save multiple plots as individual PDFs with unique names in R

Tags: r, variables, pdf, data-science, naming

I have a function that creates a plot and saves it as a pdf file. I plan on running this function in a loop for 100+ columns of a dataset. My question is how to make each pdf file uniquely named so it doesnt overwrite the previous file every time a new one is made. I tried to make it work with C integer format
`pdf(file = "~/PTY/Data/ROC Curves/ROC%03d.pdf", onefile = F, width = 7, height = 7)`
with the intended outcome of titling each plot ROC001, ROC002... but it still overwrites each new one as ROC001.

```
createROC <- function(x) {
  
  ROCtable <- createNAtable(x) #create dataset w/out NAs
  x_NA <-x[!is.na(x)]          #create analyte vector w/out NAs
  
  #create ROC variable
  newROC <- rocit(score = x_NA, class = ROCtable$DSM, negref = "0", method = "non")
  
  #create pdf
  pdf(file = "~/PTY/Data/ROC Curves/ROC%03d.pdf", onefile = F, width = 7, height = 7)
                           
  #create ROC plot
  plot(newROC, legend = F)

  dev.off()
  }
```

My function takes a vector (data1$IL6, data1$age, etc) as an input. Ideally, I would be able to title each plot after the input (IL6, age, etc).

Thank you ahead of time for your help

Comment: Difficult to help you without a sample of your data!

Comment: Pls provide minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are opening and closing the graphics device with each plot, and the counter resets at `001` each time. You need one call to `pdf()`, followed by all of your calls to `plot()`, followed by `dev.off()`, like so:

```r
# Some data with named columns
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 21:30)

# A plotting function without `pdf()` and `dev.off()`
create_plot <- function(x, main) {
  plot(x, main = main)
}

# Open graphics device
pdf(file = "filename-%03d.pdf", onefile = FALSE)

# Apply plotting function to each column of `df` in a loop
for (j in 1:3) {
  create_plot(df[, j], names(df)[j])
}

# Close graphics device
dev.off()
```

This should generate `filename-001.pdf`, `filename-002.pdf`, and `filename-003.pdf` in your working directory.